# How to properly style Angular v15 Material Component's internals

Tags: angular, sass, angular-material, angular-components

Migrated from Materials 14->15. Ignoring their documentation, we of course changed the internal styles of components using class names that have now changed, breaking everything. What I'm looking for is how do I properly create custom color styles for the internals of each component through theming.

An example is the button, I want to change the background color when the button is disabled from gray to blue. What we did in v14 was just change the styles for the class "mat-button-disabled".

How do I style components for materials v15?
Does anyone have an example of this?

I've tried updating the primary theme's color object's background palette with an "on-surface" value that we're loading into all component themes.

I've tried hardcoding, which is what I don't want to do with

```
  .mat-mdc-raised-button:disabled {
    --mdc-protected-button-disabled-container-color: mat.get-color-from-palette($primary-palette, 500);
      background-color: mat.get-color-from-palette($primary-palette, 500);
  }
```

Also added a class to the button. The style was overwritten though by "mat-mdc-raised-button:disabled"

```
  .custom-button {
    @include button.disabled-container-fill-color(pink);
  }
```

Here's another change that is currently working, but it doesn't feel right.

```
  .mat-mdc-raised-button[disabled][disabled] {
    --mdc-protected-button-disabled-container-color: #{mat.get-color-from-palette($accent-palette, 500, 0.3)};
    --mdc-protected-button-disabled-label-text-color: #{mat.get-color-from-palette($background, background, 0.3)}
  }
```

Here's my current theme

```
    @use 'sass:map';
    @use '@angular/material' as mat;
    
    $primary-palette: (
      50: #e3e4e8,
      100: #b9bcc5,
      200: #8b909f,
      300: #5c6479,
      400: #39425c,
      500: #232d6a,
      600: #131d39,
      700: #101831,
      800: #0c1429,
      900: #060b1b,
      A100: #5a7cff,
      A200: #2753ff,
      A400: #0032f3,
      A700: #002cda,
      contrast: (
        50: #000000,
        100: #000000,
        200: #000000,
        300: #ffffff,
        400: #ffffff,
        500: #ffffff,
        600: #ffffff,
        700: #ffffff,
        800: #ffffff,
        900: #ffffff,
        A100: #000000,
        A200: #ffffff,
        A400: #ffffff,
        A700: #ffffff,
      )
    );
    
    $accent-palette: (
      50: #e4ebf3,
      100: #bbcee0,
      200: #8eadcc,
      300: #618cb7,
      400: #3f73a7,
      500: #0075c9,
      600: #1a5290,
      700: #154885,
      800: #113f7b,
      900: #0a2e6a,
      A100: #9cbcff,
      A200: #6999ff,
      A400: #3676ff,
      A700: #1c65ff,
      contrast: (
        50: #000000,
        100: #000000,
        200: #000000,
        300: #000000,
        400: #ffffff,
        500: #ffffff,
        600: #ffffff,
        700: #ffffff,
        800: #ffffff,
        900: #ffffff,
        A100: #000000,
        A200: #000000,
        A400: #ffffff,
        A700: #ffffff
      )
    );
    
    $warn-palette: (
      50: #ffebee,
      100: #ffcdd2,
      200: #ef9a9a,
      300: #e57373,
      400: #ef5350,
      500: #f44336,
      600: #e53935,
      700: #d32f2f,
      800: #c62828,
      900: #b71c1c,
      A100: #ff8a80,
      A200: #ff5252,
      A400: #ff1744,
      A700: #d50000,
      contrast: (
        50: #000000,
        100: #000000,
        200: #000000,
        300: #000000,
        400: #000000,
        500: #ffffff,
        600: #ffffff,
        700: #ffffff,
        800: #ffffff,
        900: #ffffff,
        A100: #000000,
        A200: #ffffff,
        A400: #ffffff,
        A700: #ffffff,
      )
    );
    
    $text: map.get($primary-palette, 900);
    $secondary-text: map.get($primary-palette, 300);
    $light-text: white;
    $light-secondary-text: rgba(white, 0.6);
    $dividers: map.get($primary-palette, 100);
    $focused: map.get($accent-palette, 500);
    $background: white;
    $secondaryBackground: #f5f5f8;
    $success: #0ccf9e;
    $lite-success: #b4f0e1;
    $caution: #ffb300;
    $fab-background: #ffdf1c;
    $highlight: #ebf6ff;
    $text-highlight: #ffff00;
    $warning: #e539351a;
    $warning-outline: #e53935;
    $tabsicons: #f581f1;
    $polygon-on: #1efac180;
    $polygon-off: #1b1a1c33;
    $slider-gradient-1: #70cdfc;
    $slider-gradient-2: #9dfcff;
    $slider-gradient-3: #faff86;
    $slider-gradient-4: #fdcb2b;
    $slider-gradient-5: #fb3502;
    $slider-thumb-1: #8f4444;
    $slider-thumb-2: #08c557;
    $loading-backdrop: #1B1A1C;
    
    $background-palette: (
      status-bar: map.get($accent-palette, 500),
      app-bar: map.get($primary-palette, 900),
      background: $background,
      hover: rgba(map.get($accent-palette, 50), 0.2),
      card: white,
      dialog: $background,
      disabled-button: map.get($accent-palette, 500),
      raised-button: white,
      focused-button: $focused,
      selected-button: map.get($accent-palette, 50),
      selected-disabled-button: map.get($accent-palette, 100),
      disabled-button-toggle: map.get($accent-palette, 100),
      unselected-chip: map.get($accent-palette, 300),
      disabled-list-option: map.get($primary-palette, 200),
      tooltip: map.get($primary-palette, 700),
      secondary-background: $secondaryBackground,
      custom-fab: map.get($accent-palette, 700),
      active-accent: rgba($success, 0.2),
      dropdown-background: $highlight,
      loading-backdrop: $loading-backdrop,
    );
    
    $foreground-palette: (
      base: map.get($accent-palette, 500),
      divider: $dividers,
      dividers: $dividers,
      disabled: map.get($accent-palette, 100),
      disabled-button: map.get($primary-palette, 100),
      disabled-text: map.get($primary-palette, 100),
      elevation: map.get($primary-palette, 300),
      hint-text: $text,
      secondary-text: $secondary-text,
      icon: map.get($accent-palette, 50),
      icons: map.get($accent-palette, 50),
      text: $text,
      slider-min: rgba(map.get($accent-palette, 700), 0.87),
      slider-off: rgba(map.get($accent-palette, 700), 0.26),
      slider-off-active: rgba(map.get($accent-palette, 700), 0.38),
      active-accent: $success,
      caution: $caution,
      tab-icon: #f581f1,
      slider-gradient-1: #70cdfc,
      slider-gradient-2: #9dfcff,
      slider-gradient-3: #faff86,
      slider-gradient-4: #fdcb2b,
      slider-gradient-5: #fb3502,
      slider-thumb-1: #8f4444,
      slider-thumb-2: #08c557,
      warning: #e539351a,
      warning-outline: #e53935,
      polygon-on: #1efac180,
      polygon-off: #1b1a1c33,
      selected: rgba($focused, 0.1),
      inactive-icon: #5F5F60,
      on-surface: pink
    );
    
    $primary-palette: mat.define-palette($primary-palette, 500);
    
    $accent-palette: mat.define-palette($accent-palette, 500);
    
    $warn-palette: mat.define-palette($warn-palette, 700);
    
    $custom-typography-config: mat.define-typography-config(
      $font-family: 'Aeonik',
    );
    
    $primary-theme: (
      color: (
        primary: $primary-palette,
        accent: $accent-palette,
        warn: $warn-palette,
        is-dark: false,
        foreground: $foreground-palette,
        background: $background-palette,
      ),
      typography: $custom-typography-config,
      density: 0
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Add to styles.css

```
.mdc-button[disabled] {
  background: blue !important;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**